# How to linearize this second order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I want to ***linearize*** this second order non linear differential equation arround P($\pi/2 $,0)

$\frac{d^2y}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}-9.8\sin(y)=5\sin(3t)$

I undestand how to linearize single variable functions like $f(x)=Cos(x)$, but I'm clueless with the differential equation case.

Comment: Replace $\sin(y)$ with a local linear approximation.

Comment: So for my point, $ Sin(y)=Sin(0)+Cos(0)(y-0)=y $, Am I right?

Comment: What does $(π/2,0)$ denote, a pair $(t,y)$ or a pair $(y,\dot y)$? It also makes no sense as there is no constant solution with that forcing term, and the forcing is so large that it can not be considered a small perturbation. Or is that for an infinitesimal time increase? Then you would need a triple $(t,y(t),y'(t))$ to start any sensible calculation.

Comment: Try introducing $z = \dot{y}$ and $t = 1$. Then $\dot{z} = \ddot{y}$, so you can rewrite your equation as a system of three first-order equations.